# Cannot read property 'dasherize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5

When i tried to run this command:

```
ng generate component <component-name>
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'dasherize' of undefined
Cannot read property 'dasherize' of undefined
```

My angular config:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.1
Node: 7.5.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.2
@angular/cli: 1.7.1
@angular/material: 5.2.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.4.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.34
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.1
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

I've tried to remove node_modules, npm cache clean, node install and none of that worked.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9662

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it by updating;

@ angular-devkit/core
from "0.0.23" to "0.4.2"
and 
@ angular-devkit/schematics
from"0.0.42" to "0.4.2"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply need to use the `@Angular/Cli` in your project without the extended features provided by all the libraries of Angular DevKit (described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#packages)).

In your `package.json` you can simply set inside your devDependencies 
`"@angular-devkit/core":"0.4.6"` ignoring other libraries like `schematics` and `package-update` which you can remove entirely.

In this way, you can use shortcuts aliases without problems like this one to create new components

> ng g c my-new-component

Tested with `"@angular/cli": "1.7.3"`

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalled the existing packages `@angular-devkit/core` and `@angular-devkit/schematics` and installed the latest helped me

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/core
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/schematics
```

then install the latest

```
npm install @angular-devkit/core  --save-dev
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I updated the package `@angular-devkit/schematics` to the latest one and it started working.

Hope this will resolve your issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful code snippet :

```
 "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.8",
 "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.6.8",
 "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.1",
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This might answer the question. Would you mind extending it, for fellow programmers, to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem?